# Retrieving email address from Yesod OpenID

Tags: haskell, openid, yesod

Is there any way to retrieve a user's email address after authenticating with Yesod's OpenId implementation?

In my test app, the redirection and authentication occur correctly, and maybeAuthId gives me an id to the corresponding entry in my database. However, that identity is stored as a URL.

I can work with this, but it'd be nice to also get the actual email used to authenticate as other OpenId packages allow. Is this possible with Yesod's OpenId? Is there something I can do with authOpenIdExtended (unclear how to use it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into this again, I found an answer:

First, we need to use authOpenIdExtended with the right parameters:

```
authPlugins _ = [authOpenIdExtended [("openid.ns.ax", "http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0"), 
                                     ("openid.ax.mode", "fetch_request"), 
                                     ("openid.ax.type.email", "http://axschema.org/contact/email"),
                                     ("openid.ax.required", "email")
                                     ]]
```

I found these values from this page: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID and verified them to work with Google and Yahoo.

Then, to use our retrieved email address, we call "credsExtra creds" on the creds parameter passed to getAuthId. This gives us a list of tuples containing the response from the OpenId provider. When using the parameters above to authOpenIdExtended we find our email in the key/value tuples with the values "openid.ax.value.email" (for Yahoo) or "openid.ext1.value.email" (for Google). I was expecting Google to also use the "openid.ax.value.email" key, but close enough.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [GoogleEmail](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-auth/latest/doc/html/Yesod-Auth-GoogleEmail.html) module. One thing you need to keep in mind is that you can't necessarily trust every OpenID provider out there. If you use the email address for anything important, a nefarious user could simply set up an OpenID provider that let's him/her claim whichever address he/she wishes.

Comment: I think I understand how to use authOpenIdExtended (copying the list of options in GoogleEmail.hs), however I don't see how to get the email address once I'm back in my handler. There's a call to lookupGetParam in GoogleEmail.hs, but it's too late to do that once we're back in my code, right? Am i misreading what's going on? If it matters I'm using yesod-auth 1.0.1 (can't get newer to work).

Comment: You also make a very good point about not using the email address for anything important. My ids will be based off the id returned through OpenId, I just want to get the email address as a convenience.

Comment: I haven't tried via authOpenIdExtended myself, but I think [credsExtra](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-auth/1.0.2/doc/html/Yesod-Auth.html#v:credsExtra) will have the information you need.

Comment: I think I'm getting very lost in the framework.. To use credsExtra I need a Creds. From my getHomeR function, how would I get one?